# KeyError - Pandas

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, sklearn-pandas

I found a code for text classification in tensorflow and when I try to run this code: https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/feature_columns I get an error.

I used the dataset from here: https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text_clas.py", line 35, in <module>
    train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
  File "text_clas.py", line 27, in df_to_dataset
    labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  File "/home/yildiz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 809, in pop
    result = self[item]
  File "/home/yildiz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/yildiz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'target'
```

When I printed df.index.name I got NONE. So is the dataset not correct or am I doing something wrong?

I changen the dataframe.head() to print(dataframe.head()) and got this output:

```
   0  ...  @switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww, that's a bummer.  You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D
0  0  ...  is upset that he can't update his Facebook by ...                                                                  
1  0  ...  @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Man...                                                                  
2  0  ...    my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire                                                                   
3  0  ...  @nationwideclass no, it's not behaving at all....                                                                  
4  0  ...                      @Kwesidei not the whole crew                                                                   

[5 rows x 6 columns]
1023999  train examples
256000  validation examples
320000  test examples
```

Comment: your dataframe (which has the variablename dataframe) does not have a column named 'target' but you try to pop that column. You might want to post the code that produces the error, instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: Check my edited post, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the same csv file. loaded and run command with popup. It works. make sure u have loaded right DataFrame. Are You sure that DataFrame is named 'dataframe' ? or just 'df'? then df.pop('target') should work

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't loaded the data correctly. Make sure that your train DataFrame is not empty.

If it is ok, then check if 'target' is a column name (by executing
`print(train.head())`,for example, or even `print(dataframe.head())` after you have read your csv file).

Also, I am not really sure what df.index.name would print. Did you mean to write `df.index.values`? (Though index probably has nothing to do with your problem.)

**EDIT:**

Okay, so it seems that you have no columns assigned to your dataframe. You can do that by `dataframe.columns = ['target', ...] # and pick the other names`

Also, your header is the first column so your should set `header=False` when you call `read_csv` and then set the columns (if you don't do that then you will lose the first row).

Note that `df.index.name` does not make any sense (like I said before), so printing `NONE` does not mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

So ok this is the code I use

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

encoding='utf-8-sig'
dataframe = pd.read_csv('~/Schreibtisch/TwitterBot/training_dataset_twitter.csv')
dataframe.head()

train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
print(len(train), ' train examples')
print(len(val), ' validation examples')
print(len(test), ' test examples')


# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop('target')
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe),labels))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

batch_size = 5 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

for feature_batch, label_batch in train_ds.take(1):
  print('Every feature:', list(feature_batch.keys()))
  print('A batch of ages:', feature_batch['age'])
  print('A batch of targets:', label_batch )
```

Comment: You should probably edit your initial post with this post. Replace ```dataframe.head()``` with ```print(dataframe.head())``` (if your are not in jupyter) and tell me what the results is. is it an empty DF and if not, does it contain the ```target``` column?